# Speed up backup of just ACLs on large file systems

Tags: backup, permissions, performance, access-control-list, optimization

I'm trying to make quick backups of just the ACLs on large GNU/Linux file systems. Extended permissions are not really necessary.

I run 4 little benchmarks on a small partition just to make an estimation of the elapsed time (seconds) and produced file sizes (megabytes).

- `getfacl -R -p /backup/dir > out_file`: 58.715s (36MB)
- `find /backup/dir -printf "%m %u:%g %p \n" > out_file` : 54.053s (27MB)
- `find /backup/dir -printf "%m %p \n" > out_file` : **0.763s** (26MB)
- `ls -laR /backup/dir > out_file` : **4.865s** (20MB)

So `ls` is the best solution if need the user:group.

Ideally, the *out_file* should look like:

```
755 user:group /full/path/to/dir
744 user:group /full/path/to/file
...
```

But as far as I know getting the full path to the file from `ls` requires extra commands which will slow down the process. We are talking about very big file systems.

Isn't there a better (faster/more efficient) tool than `ls` to handle this?

Why does `find` slow down so dramatically when retrieving user:group info in comparison to `ls`?

As a plus, `ls` can also handle escaping special characters on filenames (with the `-b` option).

**Solved:** (thanks to @shodanshok)
First time after `sync`:

- `getfacl -n -R -p /backup/dir > out_file`: 19.561s (36MB)

But the second time running the same command:

- `getfacl -n -R -p /backup/dir > out_file`: 2.496s (36MB)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, `getfacl` can be CPU bound by the username-resolving process. Try adding the `-n` switch, for example issuing `getfacl -n -R -p /backup/dir > out_file`

During benchmarks, pay special attention to the inode/dentry cache, as it can easily skew your timed test. Before each benchmark, issue the following command to empty both caches: `sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

Comment: The `-n` did bring a huge improvement. From what I understand, the `sync` will write temporal files to the disk and the "3" in drop_caches will clear up the caches to make some room for the new data, right?

Comment: True. As you can see, your second `getfacl` run is much faster, due to metadata being cached by the first execution.